# IIS Server Error 401.2 in '/' Application. Access is denied

Tags: iis, server

Here is the full error

Server Error in '/' Application.
Access is denied.
Description: An error occurred while accessing the resources required to serve this request. The server may not be configured for access to the requested URL.

Error message 401.2.: Unauthorized: Logon failed due to server configuration.  Verify that you have permission to view this directory or page based on the credentials you supplied and the authentication methods enabled on the Web server.  Contact the Web server's administrator for additional assistance.

Please help!

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/troubleshoot/using-failed-request-tracing/troubleshooting-failed-requests-using-tracing-in-iis

Answer (score 0):

This error can occur when the authentication method that is configured in the web.config file for the Microsoft Dynamics NAV Web client is not enabled in Internet Information Services (IIS). The Microsoft Dynamics NAV Web client can be configured to use either Windows authentication or forms authentication. By default, the Microsoft Dynamics NAV Web client uses Windows authentication.

- When you use Windows authentication, the Windows authentication
  feature must be turned on in IIS and enabled on the website for the
  Microsoft Dynamics NAV Web client.
- When you use forms authentication, both forms authentication and
  anonymous authentication must be enabled on the website for Microsoft
  Dynamics NAV Web client.

1.To turn on the Windows Authentication feature in IIS

- Use Internet Information Services (IIS) Manager to turn on Windows
  authentication on IIS. For more information, see How to: [Install and
  Configure Internet Information Services for Microsoft Dynamics NAV
  Web Client](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics-nav/how-to--install-and-configure-internet-information-services-for-microsoft-dynamics-nav-web-client)

2.To enable an authentication method on the Microsoft Dynamics NAV Web client website

- On the computer that is running Microsoft Dynamics NAV Web Server
  components, to open Internet Information Services (IIS) Manager and
  do one of the following:

  a. In Windows 7, on the Start menu, in the Search Programs and Files box, type inetmgr,
  and then press Enter.

  b. In Windows Server 2008 R2, on the Start menu, choose All Programs, choose Administrative Tools, and then choose Internet Information Service (IIS) Manager.
- In the Connections pane, under Sites, choose Microsoft Dynamics NAV 2018 Web Client.
- Under IIS, double-click Authentication.
- To enable an authentication method, in the Authentication pane, choose the authentication, and then choose Enable in the Actions pane.
- Restart the web server.

3.To restart IIS

- In the Connections pane of Internet Information Services (IIS)
  Manager, choose the root node for your computer, and then in the
  Actions pane, choose Restart.

For more information you can refer to this link: [Troubleshooting: Server Error in '-' Application. Access Denied](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics-nav/troubleshooting--server-error-in-----application.-access-denied)